# Python: Command line arguments are incorrect

Tags: python, django, shell

I do want to verify a Django framework generated hash with the PassLib library
(https://pythonhosted.org/passlib/lib/passlib.hash.django_std.html)

My python script looks like that:

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.7

import sys
from passlib.hash import django_pbkdf2_sha256 as handler

def verifizieren(password_plain, django_hash):
     handler.verify(password_plain, django_hash)

def main():
    print (sys.argv[1])
    print (sys.argv[2])
    verifizieren(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2])

main()
```

When I call my script in the command line with

```
python myscript.py test pbkdf2_sha256$12000$EkKZXYXv0adl$GZppRyXed3a0y1uZMBR/F8Mu/rnpsN+7atY4hZAwlrQ=
```

Somehow, my hash is cutted. Instead of

```
pbkdf2_sha256$12000$EkKZXYXv0adl$GZppRyXed3a0y1uZMBR/F8Mu/rnpsN+7atY4hZAwlrQ=
```

my argv[2] is

```
pbkdf2_sha2562000/F8Mu/rnpsN+7atY4hZAwlrQ=
```

Why is python cutting away the rest of my command line parameter?
And how can I avoid this?

Comment: Python's not touching it; `$` is special in shells and you're shell is doing something to it. Try putting the argument in single quotes.

Comment: Thanks! I putted it in double-quoted and it didn't worked. That's why i thought it would have been a python error. I didn't tried single quotes
I'm very new to this topic. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to call your script as follows:

```
python myscript.py test 'pbkdf2_sha256$12000$EkKZXYXv0adl$GZppRyXed3a0y1uZMBR/F8Mu/rnpsN+7atY4hZAwlrQ='
```

the single quotes around the second argument will protect the string from being interpreted by the shell, as the shell understands anything that follows a `$` as a shell variable.

As `$EkKZXYXv0adl` and `$GZppRyXed3a0y1uZMBR` obviously do not exist in your shell environment, they expand to nothing.

Comment: Interesting to know that these variables are threated as environment variables. I never uses variables in the shell, so I did not have seen the mistake there. Thanks!